# Is possible to get automatic cast from user-defined type to std::string using cout?

Tags: c++, casting, stdstring, implicit-conversion, user-defined-types

As in the question, if I define a string operator in my class:

```
class Literal {
  operator string const () {
    return toStr ();
  };

  string toStr () const;
};
```

and then I use it:

```
Literal l1 ("fa-2bd2bc3e0");
cout << (string)l1 << " Declared" << endl;
```

with an explicit cast everything goes right, but if I remove the (string) the compiler says that it needs a cast operator declared in std::string. Shouldn't it cast my type automatically?
SOLVED: I'm overloading operator<< (ostream& os, const Literal& l).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No..  std::string would have to have a constructor that took Literal as an argument.

What you could do is overload operator << for your Literal class and have it cast and insert into the stream in there.

```
ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &stream, const Literal &rhs)
{
    stream << (string) rhs;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: If you are planning to use your class with the stream operations, you really should overload the << and >> operators. It makes using the class cleaner.

Comment: c++ has it's own set of conversion operators. Do not use c casts

Comment: A conversion constructor and conversion operator are equivalent when determining whether a function call is viable. The real reason the compiler won't do an implicit cast here is more complicated.

Comment: @BЈовић the sample code uses the cast only as a placeholder for the string formatting logic that would be required of `Literal` (the user defined type). In practice, it is likely that the UDT has numerous properties, each supporting the ostream operator, and the aggregate's ostream operator would simply append them one by one.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:  Keep using a cast or `toStr()`, or write your own `operator<<` function.  (I would prefer `l1.toStr()` to `(string)l1`.)

Long answer:
This might work if the Standard Library had a function

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, std::string const& );
```

Which it almost does, but not technically.  Both `ostream` and `string` are really typedefs of template instantiations.  And there's a template function for inserting one into the other.

```
// This is somewhat simplified.  For the real definitions, see the Standard
// and/or your complying implementation's headers.
namespace std {
  typedef basic_string<char> string;
  typedef basic_ostream<char> ostream;

  template <typename CharT>
  basic_ostream<CharT>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<CharT>&, 
    basic_string<CharT> const&);
}
```

So when you use `cout << str` where the type of `str` is `std::string`, it can figure out to use that template function, with `CharT = char`.

But C++ doesn't allow you to have the compiler figure out both an implicit type conversion (`Literal` to `string`) and deduce template function template parameters (`CharT = char`) on the same call.

Comment: Well said!  Incidentally, this is why *operator const char \*(){}* **will** work whereas *operator string(){}* won't.